# Sorbet type-checking on tree class with a custom schema?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I have a custom tree-like class (`MyTree`) that stores data under hierarchical keys, (similar to filesystem paths). It exposes methods `get` and `set`, each of which operate on `"."`-separated keys. An instance of `MyTree` is given a schema when instantiated that specifies type for each key (for purposes of this question, consider the types of all values stored to be `Nilable`): each defined key:

```rb
t = MyTree.new({
  a: {
    b: { type: String },
    c: { type: Integer },
  },
  d: { type: Hash },
})

t.set('a.b', 'bar')
t.get('a.b')  # => 'bar'
```

I am trying to augment this class with `sorbet`, so that it would work like this:

```rb
# Sorbet type error (vaulue under a.b should be a `String`)
t.set('a.b', 3)

# Sorbet method error (`#length` doesn't exist on `Integer`)
t.set('a.c', 1)
x = t.get('a.c')
x.length
```

But I'm not sure how to make the schema for a given `MyTree` instance legible to sorbet. Is this possible?